# Run an application and get the handle to its window. My code doesn't work properly in Windows 10 x64

Tags: delphi, windows-10, handle, sendmessage, createprocess

My main application (A) gets data and writes back results using a companion application (B) which  interfaces the database (every different database's schema needs a different program B).
The two applications communicate in this way:

Step 1) A launches B communicating its own handle (A_WindowHandle) and freezes(?) waiting response from B

Step 2) B (in FormCreate) sends back its own B_WindowHandle to A

Note) Now each application knows the windowHandle of the other and can communicate via SendMessage.

Step 3) A resumes working supposing having received the B_WindowHandle (which in Win10 X64 is not true) and immediately A sends its first request to B

The two applications have born in Windows XP and they have always been fine working till now when they were first installed in a Windows 10 X64 (they worked in Windows 7 X64).

The problem is that before Windows 10 X64, Program_A immediately received back the B_WindowHandle; now the message from B arrives with some delay or better to say, A resumes executing too early supposing to have a good B_WindowHandle but this one has still the value of zero.

I always supposed my code wasn't very good as (see step 1) program_A is garanteed to be freezing until it gets response from CreateProcess, WaitForInputIdle; perhaps not enough to get the first message from B (step 2).

But it always worked and i forgot, i had to care to write this code in a proper way. But which is the proper way?

I have been trying putting some delay in program_A, sleep(5000), just after the launch of Program_B but it doesn't help.

Thanks
edoardo

Notes:

- A and B are 32 bits applications. A is written in Delphi 5, B in Delphi 7.
- A and B are installed in the same folder_X which is directly under C. I know it is not the adviced place but in this folder_X there are so many different kind of subFolders and files that i liked to keep together for ease of use (the programs should become portable, but it is not yet).
- There is never more than 1 instance of A and B running.
- Program B can be started in tree different ways: by program_A, scheduled, manually; only the first mode interest us here.
- When B starts, it creates two datamodules and the main form (in this order).
- While executing A can start and close B several times (sometimes the B form is visible, sometimes not); every time A needs data from the database or has to write to it, checks if B is executing and, if not, launches it.
- B is not always running for two reasons: firstly sometimes B has to show something to the user and hence it must be visible, sometimes it doesn't need it (I didn't know how to switch it from visible to invisible and viceversa); secondly A and B work with huge amount of data and once, 20 years ago, there was not much available memory and it was better to close B when not in use.
- Apart from the first message arriving late, all the communications between A and B work well.

Code used:
Step 1 A creates B communicating his handle

```
//in Program A:
...
try
  //SAETXXXX : constant with the name program B
  //ModLnc   : String value: "V"/"I" Visible/Invisible
  //Handle:  : Windows Handle of A
  RunCmd.RunCommand(SAETXXXX, ModLnc + #32 + IntToStr(Handle));

  //here program_A supposes having received the message with    <<<<<<
  // handle of program_B  which in Win10 X64 is not true        <<<<<< 
  // See step 3

  is_SaetXXXX_Vivo:= true; //i.e.: is_B_running:= true
except
  raise EAnomalia.Create(MSG_MANCAPGMINTERFC);
end;
...

Procedure RunCommand(const Cmd, Params: String);
var
SI: TStartupInfo;
PI: TProcessInformation;
CmdLine: String;
begin
//Fill record with zero byte values
FillChar(SI, SizeOf(SI), 0);
//Set mandatory record field
SI.cb := SizeOf(SI);
//Ensure Windows mouse cursor reflects launch progress
SI.dwFlags := StartF_ForceOnFeedback;
//Set up command line
CmdLine := Cmd;
if Length(Params) > 0 then
  CmdLine := CmdLine + #32 + Params;
//Try and launch child process. Raise exception on failure
Win32Check(
  CreateProcess(
    nil, PChar(CmdLine), nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, SI, PI));

//Wait until process has started its main message loop
WaitForInputIdle(PI.hProcess, Infinite);
//Close process and thread handles
CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
end;
```

Step 2) B (in FormCreate) sends back its own B_WindowHandle to A

```
    //unit Global var
    ModoLnc    : char;       //Visible/Invisible/other(scheduled launch) 
    HWNDApplCli: HWND;       //A_WindowHandle
    WMsg01     : Cardinal;   //Windows idMessage (got from registration)
    ...
procedure TfmProgramB.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  is_FormVisibile:= true; //unit global var form must be visible (for the moment)
  ...

  self.Caption:= TIT_PGM_CONN; //caption depends from connected DB
  
  //creates some objects (TLists) 
  //reads Inifile and sets form position
  //sets some date
  ....

  try
    NArgRic := NumberOfArguments(CmdLine, true);

    if NArgRic = 1 then begin
       //a* manually launched 
       .....
    end else begin
       //a* Launched by A .OR. Windows scheduled launch 
       ....
       ModoLnc:= ExtractArgument(CmdLine, 1, true)[1];

       if (ModoLnc = MODLNC_VISIB) or
          (ModoLnc = MODLNC_INVIS)    then begin
          //a* Launched by A

          if (ModoLnc = MODLNC_INVIS) then begin
             Application.ShowMainForm:= false;
             is_FormVisibile:= false;
          end;


          //creates a MapFile used for future communication with program_A
          hMapFile := CreateFileMapping (....
          
          //m* get the same idMessage used by Program_A
          WMsg01 := RegisterWindowMessage(MIOWMSG_01);



          //a* gets A_WindowHandle
          HWNDApplCli:= StrToInt(ExtractArgument(CmdLine, 2, true));


          if HWNDApplCli <> 0 then begin
                                                                                         
               //HWNDApplCli: A_WindowHandle
               //WMsg01     : idMessage
               //WMsg01_wpManigliaServer: tells program_A, next prm is B_WindowHandle
               //Self.Handle: B_WindowHandle
               SendMessage(HWNDApplCli, WMsg01, WMsg01_wpManigliaServer,
                          Integer(Self.Handle));
          end;
       end else begin
          //a* Windows scheduled launch
          ....
       end;
    end;
  except
     raise;
  end;
end;
```

Step 3) A resumes working supposing having received the B_WindowHandle (which in Win10 X64 is not true) and immediately A sends its first request to B

```
// here how program_A receives B_WindowHandle (but late) 
procedure TfmProgramA.WndProc(Var TheMsg: TMessage);
begin
  if TheMsg.Msg = WMsg01 then begin
    case TheMsg.wParam of

      WMsg01_wpManigliaServer :
         begin
        
            is_ManigliaServerRicevuta:= true;  //is_B_Handle_received
            ...

            HWNDApplSrv:=  TheMsg.lParam;
         end;
     .....
  end;

  Inherited WndProc(TheMsg);
end;
```

Comment: Assuming all else works try adding a Named Mutex or something, my notes on `WaitForInputIdle` state: _Waits only once for any of the Threads of the Process to become idle; subsequent calls return immediately_

Comment: Cut it down to minimalistic examples and compile those, without any futher code. Preferably again 32bit executables. That would ensure sending messages is the culprit and not all the other tasks that you erased in the example code.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than A using `WaitForInputIdle()` at all (which has caveats! See [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100325-00/?p=14493) and [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100326-00/?p=14483)), just make B not send its HWND to A until B is actually ready for comms. For instance, by *posting* itself a private message, and then sending its HWND to A when that message is processed by B's message loop.  And don't make A *assume* that `WMsg01_wpManigliaServer` has been received by the time `WaitForInputIdle()` exits.  Actually *make A wait* for `WMsg01_wpManigliaServer` to arrive before trying to use B's HWND.

You are also not taking HWND recreation into account. If A's or B's HWNDs ever change at runtime (which *can* happen!), the new HWNDs need to be exchanged again. Rather than passing HWNDs back and forth, I would just store both HWNDs in a block of shared memory allocated with `CreateFileMapping()`+`MapViewOfFile()`, and then broadcast a registered message whenever either HWND changes, and have both A and B listen for that message.  Whenever A or B needs to send a message to the other party, use that party's HWND that is currently stored in the shared memory block.

Or better, simply don't use HWNDs for comms between A and B to begin with.  Use more direct channels instead, such as pipes, sockets, ActiveX/COM, etc.  Pipes would be especially useful with `CreateProcess()` as redirected STDIN/STDOUT handles for B to use to communicate with A.